# mysqldump: Error: 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query' when trying to dump tablespaces

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a dump of a database on one of our (small) servers. I am running this command:

```
sudo mysqldump --opt -u [name] -p [password] smx > smxfeb52014.sql
```

And I'm getting this error back:

```
mysqldump: Error: 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query' when trying to dump tablespaces
mysqldump: Got error: 2006: MySQL server has gone away when selecting the database
```

I've set me max_allowed_packet to 500 and restarted mysql but no dice.

Any tips?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did u get to resolve this error Mike?